# Nested elements with min-width max-height

Tags: css

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rodneyrehm/nqAwm/

I've got a `<div>` inside another. Both are positioned absolutely. Both should adjust their size depending on their content within min-width and max-width bounds. While the outer `<div>` behaves as expected, the inner does not. Have a look at the fiddle to see what I've tried already… Any ideas on how to make that nested element respect min-width and max-width?

Comment: can you explain the 'real life situation'? what you need to achieve? there may be another workaround?

Comment: i dont understand the question; why do you have so much inline styles and will style the same elements?

Comment: Looks to me as though the nested `divs` are respecting the `min-width' & `max-with`  [see the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danferth/nqAwm/1/) or am i missing the problem to the question?

Comment: Real life situation: [Issue #18 / jQuery.contextMenu](https://github.com/medialize/jQuery-contextMenu/issues/18) [demo](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html).

Comment: I was just pointed to [The calculated width of the absolutely positioned containing block is 0 (or respectively its specifically set min-width)](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=429894#p429894) - so I guess I'll have to find another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is just the way it is: [The calculated width of the absolutely positioned containing block is 0 (or respectively its specifically set min-width](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=429894#p429894)